# Equivalent of git log command for Heroku

Tags: git, heroku

I am wondering if there is an equivalent of `git log` for `Heroku` that shows the push history on heroku remote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the heroku cli running the command : `heroku releases` should do the trick.

Source : https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-the-cli

Comment: Is there any options, for this command, that give more information about the deploys?

Comment: Not that I know of. What kind of infos do you need ? You already access the release number, the commit message, the author and the timestamp.

Comment: The git log of deployed changes would be nice.

Answer (score 1):

I complement this question by saying that `heroku releases` will do that, but if you want to know more about the release you can do:

For version 1: `heroku releases:info v1`

For version 2: `heroku releases:info v2`

And so on...

> You can check more info in the documentation of heroku:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/releases